# Rails pagy route without pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagy

I have a Rails API app. I use [Pagy](https://github.com/ddnexus/pagy) nicely and works perfectly. However, I would like to call the same route|service|endpoint for getting all records, ignoring pagination. Is this possible?

Comment: You could use a query params saying you want all records?

Comment: Please post what your code does now (or some semblance of such) so people answering have something to work with when answering.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a flag as query params and based on input you can set/ignore pagination

Answer (score 0):

it would be able to  work with an extra param, in this case we will use `params[:show_all]`

```
def index
  unless params[:show_all]
    @pagy, @products = pagy(Product.kept, items: page_size, page: page_number)
        render json: @products
  else
    Product.kept
  end
end
```